# Cannot crawl some sites with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I've been using scrapy last 2 years. Now there is some problem I cannot find out what problem is this. I am crawling about 80 sites. All of them are being crawled, but about 6 sites aren't. I am using RandomProxy middleware, RotateUserAgent middleware and splash.

So, Can you help me to figure out what problem is that. Then I'll search the solution. The site that cannot be crawled is: http://proza.ru/avtor/miliku

The error is:

```
link:http://proza.ru/avtor/miliku; message: Traceback (most recent call last): Failure: twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion.>]
```

Comment: I'd suggest you try searching that error message, you'll find quite a lot of discussions about this issue together with some advices.

Comment: disable following robots.txt, also visit that website from browser and copy all request headers, and use those same headers inside your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the [robot.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) policy causes your error. But you can try disabling *"Obey robot.txt"* rules in ***settings.py***:

> ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

Disabling this may cause site policy violations. So be careful!